# flex space between elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two flex elements and I need space between them,
I added a margin-right between them and it looks great, but the problem is when the screen is get smallest the second element go down to the new line and I have aredudant margin-right:30px and it not looks good.
How can I solve it:
[image]

[image]

I dont want to use a window resize event because if you open this ui in mobile so  in the begining you have these two items in seperate lines.

```
.item-target-scale {
        flex: 3;
        min-width: 186px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }

      .item-target-bar {
        flex:1;
        min-width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use media query for this purpose. Inspect your page and find out when does the line break occur(use devtools it gives precise viewport width in pixels).

```
    @media screen and (min-width:'calculated'px)
    {
        .item-target-scale {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

**EDIT:**

Use this if the element size is not fixed:

```js
function myFunction(){
var i=document.getElementById("target1").offsetWidth+document.getElementById("target2").offsetWidth+50;
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
if(i>=w)
{
 document.getElementById("target1").style.marginRight="0px";
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("target1").style.marginRight="30px";
}
}
```

```css
.item-target-scale {
        flex: 3;
        min-width: 186px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: 30px;
        background:green;
      }

      .item-target-bar {
        flex:1;
        min-width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        background:red;
      }
```

```html
<body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">

<div class="item-target-scale" id="target1">
dwdwdwdwd
</div>
<div class="item-target-bar" id="target2">
eegerg
</div>

</body>
```

I will need the HTML code to get the rest of the item's size but that can be done by inspecting. So, just add the remaining element's width in 'i'.

Comment: Glad to help:) Do accept it if this seems the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: What about if only the elemnt get smallest not the winow, resize the element size... the media query will not work here

Comment: How would you resize the image? Directly in the code or is it stretchable in the webpage? You have given it a min width of 186px so i am guessing image resize will be through code...

Comment: @OrtalBlumenfeldLagziel Please do tell me if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest wrapping these two elements in parent element and using `justify-content: space-between` property.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
}

.child {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
  </div>
</div>
```